# JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync, "The connection is not open"?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Hi Im developing a Web Api project using VB and am getting a weird error when trying to read the response from my service.

Here are the codes being used, please let me know if you need anymore information.

Im using Entity Framework.

Here is the Output Log:

```
Message='Action returned 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DimSuporteModelo.Sistema]'',         Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter',   Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-    type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync,     Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=SistemaController.ExecuteAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=200 (OK), Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:2421/api/Sistema/True/1, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/12/ROOT-1-130567283533102096): Loaded     'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Desig    n.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is     enabled.
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync,     Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: The connection is not open.
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.get_ServerVersion()
   at GetServerVersion(Object )
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter',     Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-    type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=SistemaController.Dispose
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Here is the code calling the web api:

```
Public Overloads Shared Function GetObjetos(Of T)(servico As String, ativo As Boolean, idCliente As Integer)
        Dim parametros As String = ""
        parametros = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", ativo, idCliente)
        Dim resposta As HttpResponseMessage = clienteHttp.GetAsync(UriServico & servico & parametros).Result
        Return resposta.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of List(Of T)()).Result
    End Function
```

Here is the controller:

```
Public Function GetSistemas(ativo As String, id As Integer) As List(Of DimSuporteModelo.Sistema)
        Return repository.GetSistemas(ativo, id)
    End Function
```

This is the function that returns the list of type 'Sistema'

```
   Public Function GetSistemas(ativo As String, id As Integer) As List(Of DimSuporteModelo.Sistema) Implements ISistema.GetSistemas
        Dim objSistemaDataSource As New SistemaDataSource
        objSistemaDataSource.Contexto.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = False
        If ativo = "True" Then
            ativo = True
        Else
            ativo = False
        End If
        Dim listaSistemas As List(Of DimSuporteModelo.Sistema) = objSistemaDataSource.SelecionaVariosPorExpressao(Function(x) x.sisAtivo = ativo AndAlso x.cliID = id And x.sisID = 4)
        Return listaSistemas
    End Function
```

Not Sure whats causing the error.. Im new to Web Api, maybe I forgot to add something?

Edit: This is the json file I get as a response, apparently the error happens during the serialization

```
{
$id: "1"
Message: "An error has occurred."
ExceptionMessage: "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
StackTrace: null
InnerException: {
$id: "2"
Message: "An error has occurred."
ExceptionMessage: "Error getting value from 'ServerVersion' on 'System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection'."
ExceptionType: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"
}
```

I can include the whole inner exception if needed(its quite long), but I didnt see anything relevant in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking thorugh my whole code, I found a mistake inside the 'Sistema' Partial Class where I had created some properties that I was creating a instance of 'SistemaDataSource', that is the class that defines my Context with the database, outside of any properties, so it was adding a instance of the connection to the Sistema objects returned by the service.. And when the JsonSerializer tried to serialize the connection, the ServerVersion would be null since the connection was closed.

```
Partial Public Class Sistema
    Dim objSistemaDataSource as new SistemaDataSource <- The problem!!!
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property RetornarNomeDoSistema As String
        Get
            Return Me.sisNome
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Hope this helps anyone that encounters the same problem, keep your code clean! :)